# Does systemd support on-failure restarts for forking daemons?

Tags: systemd, exit-status

Originally [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016717/does-systemd-support-on-failure-restarts-for-forking-daemons), told to come ask over here.  To recap that conversation--

1. No, I haven't really been able to try making the change to see what happens (not without potentially impacting a running production service).
2. RTFM due diligence done.  They don't cover this.

My original SO question follows:

Assume I have the following in my `systemd` unit file:

```
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
```

Parent process exits with status 0 (child launched successfully).  At some later point, the child dies with a non-zero status.  What happens?  `systemd` can track the child daemon process PID:

```
Process: 1768 ExecStart=/bin/mydaemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1770 (mydaemon)
```

Is `Restart=on-failure` only looking at the parent exit status, or also the child?

Comment: Ensure RemainAfterExit=no e.g. with command: systemctl show --full $service_name | fgrep -e RemainAfterExit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Something

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
ExecStart=/tmp/script.sh
ExecStop=/tmp/script.sh
Restart=on-failure
```

The script.sh contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Forking"
/tmp/myscript.sh &
```

The myscript.sh contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 60
exit 1
```

Sure enough, every 60 seconds, systemd restarts the service.

As shown here, notice the different PID's and the start times, note that it restarts the parent:

```
linux:~ # systemctl status myService.service
● myService.service - Something
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myService.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-07-10 20:43:29 CEST; 57s ago
  Process: 4393 ExecStart=/tmp/script.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4396 (script.sh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/myService.service
           ├─4396 /bin/sh /tmp/script.sh
           └─4397 sleep 60

Jul 10 20:43:29 linux.suse systemd[1]: Starting Something...
Jul 10 20:43:29 linux.suse script.sh[4393]: Forking
Jul 10 20:43:29 linux.suse systemd[1]: Started Something.
linux:~ # systemctl status myService.service
● myService.service - Something
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myService.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-07-10 20:44:29 CEST; 1s ago
  Process: 4409 ExecStop=/tmp/script.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4417 ExecStart=/tmp/script.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4420 (script.sh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/myService.service
           ├─4420 /bin/sh /tmp/script.sh
           └─4421 sleep 60

Jul 10 20:44:29 linux.suse systemd[1]: Starting Something...
Jul 10 20:44:29 linux.suse script.sh[4417]: Forking
Jul 10 20:44:29 linux.suse systemd[1]: Started Something.
```